# Beans for Qatar-type coffee?

Tags: bean-varieties

I have seen coffee prepared as in Qatar: It was mixed with cardamon, and had a light brown colour. The taste was excellent. I was told that the coffee beans were roasted only very little. Which kind of coffee beans are typically used for this coffee in Qatar, and can one get them in Europe?

Comment: If you can work out what type of beans they are, you can always roast them yourself to the desired level!

Comment: In my answer to your [other question with the same content on SA](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/57069/unroasted-beans-for-arab-coffee), I thought you meant coffee cherry tea, but it sounds like you meant qahwa arabiyyah? Let's close this question and migrate that question from [cooking.se]. Best to ask content on only one site; sorry we didn't get this done sooner.

Comment: Now I have found out that the name of this coffee is Khaleeji.

Comment: Great! I'm glad you found an answer. Would you add a self-answer with some information about [khaleeji](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khaleeji) coffee? It seems to basically mean the type of coffee found in the Persian Gulf / Eastern Arabia area. I see [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_coffee) about the concept, but it would be great to have an answer to your question here. Would you add one?

Comment: I'll do that later today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can read Arabic and also I prepare Arabian coffee as you want, so here comes the recipe

1- you have to get a very fine ground, light roasted plain coffee 1 tps / 80 ml water

2- ground cardamom 1/8 tps

3- saffron

4- 1:2 cloves / 80 ml

5- rose water 1/2 tps / 80 ml

A lot of Arabs drink it plain. Instead of sugar they eat dates along with it but you can add sugar if you wish; set your pot on a very very low heat, let it boil.

Turn the heat off and transfer it to another pot, wait until the grounds settle down the pot and pour, have fun.

Comment: by the way there is so many varieties of coffee called Arabian coffee
some use green beans "Saudi coffee", some used to call Turkish coffee as Arabian coffee also

Comment: It is nice to have someone very experienced in these brews :) Great answer!

Answer (score 5):

By now I have found out the method to prepare Khaleeji coffee as it is called. People drink it without milk or sugar.

Ingredients:

3 cups water

3 tablespoons ground coffee from Emirates

1 tablespoon ground cardamon

5 to 6 cloves

1 finger tip saffron threads

1 teaspoon rosewater

Method:

Boil water in frying pan. Add coffee. Cover and boil for 10 minutes. Add cardamon and cloves and boil for three more minutes. Remove from stove and let it cool for one minute without stirring. Put rose water and saffron into a thermos bottle. Add coffee via a sieve. Wait 5 minutes. Then the coffee will be ready to drink.